# Rotate Three.js camera around center using mouse

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm trying to rotate the camera around the center point (0, 0, 0) using the mouse but if I rotate to the right or left 180deg, then the try to rotate up or down, it doesn't rotate vertically at all.

I'm trying to use latitude/longitude coordinates then convert it to cartesian like:

```
this.camera.position.x = Math.sin(this.lat) * this.alt;
this.camera.position.z = Math.cos(this.lat) * Math.cos(this.lng) * this.alt;
this.camera.position.y = Math.cos(this.lat) * Math.sin(this.lng) * this.alt;
this.camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
```

A minimal example is here: https://jsfiddle.net/qsor9w27/2/

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest would be using [OrbitControls](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js) or [TrackballControls](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js)

See [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_orbit.html) which is using OrbitControls.

Comment: Yea, but I would prefer to do it myself so I can understand how it works.

Comment: I see :) What about using [Spherical](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=spher#Reference/Math/Spherical), it's already in Three.js and it's used to have spherical coordinates, may be better for you camera and your problem with the polar angles (phi)?